# Svelte - $: reactive statement not working

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I'm trying to build a queue for my svelte app. Basicly, my server sends messages, and they need to be executed in order, with each action waiting for the last one to finish. The model i'm currently using is this:
I built a store to store my actionQueue

```
import { writable, derived } from "svelte/store";
import type { Action } from "../types/Actions";

const initialState: Action[] = [];

let id = 0;

function createActionQueue() {
  const { subscribe, update } = writable<Action[]>(initialState);

  return {
    subscribe,
    add: (payload: Action) => {
      update((queue) => [...queue, { id: id++, ...payload }]);
    },
    next: () => {
      update((queue) => {
        queue.shift();
        return queue;
      });
    },
  };
}

export const actionQueue = createActionQueue();
export const nextAction = derived(
  actionQueue,
  ($actionQueue) => $actionQueue[0]
);
```

And on compoennts that need to listen to that actionQueue, I do this

```
  $: doNextAction($nextAction);

  function doNextAction(nextAction: Action) {
    if (nextAction) {
      if (nextAction.type === "someType") {
        doSomething();
    actionQueue.next();
      } else if (nextAction.type === "anotherType") {
        doSomethingElse();
    actionQueue.next();
      }
    }
  }
```

But sometimes, actionQueue.next() doesn't trigger an update on $nextAction. I verified this by using this command on a random component:

```
$: console.log('nextAction',$nextAction);
```

I also tried using directly $actionQueue[0] but still, it doesn't quite work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circular dependency it is.

I use `->` to denote "change in one *triggers* another", then the dep graph goes:

```
actionQueue.add() -> $nextAction -> doNextAction($nextAction) 
-> actionQueue.next() -> $nextAction -> doNextAction($nextAction) -> ...
```

As you can see `$: doNextAction($nextAction)` basically triggers itself. In order to prevent infinite loop, svelte runtime will only trigger once and stop there. Thus the behavior you see.

I put together a simpler demo to illustrate this process.

```html
<script>
let counter = 0
function add() { counter += 1 }
function next(x) { counter = x * 2 }
$: next(counter)
</script>

<h1>counter: {counter}!</h1>
<button on:click={add}>+1</button>
```

Basically `add()` maps to your `actionQueue.add()` and `next()` maps to `doNextAction()`.

Although `next()` did change `counter`, it won't trigger another round of `$: next(counter)`.

#### Solution

If you want to get around this limitation (it's actually protection), you can fool svelte runtime to oversee the circular dependency by using `setTimeout`.

```js
function doNextAction(nextAction: Action) {
  if (nextAction) {
    if (nextAction.type === 'someType') {
      doSomething()
      // the trick:
      setTimeout(() => actionQueue.next())
    } else if (nextAction.type === 'anotherType') {
      doSomethingElse()
      // the trick:
      setTimeout(() => actionQueue.next())
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the statement `actionQueue.next()` is not reachable in your case, because the property `nextAction.type`  is undefined, So even if you add a new item to the queue, the console always prints the same first element

I have created a REPL and it seems smoothly working you can check out this [link](https://svelte.dev/repl/08faf51600f54687a347ff95ff990caf?version=3.35.0)

Comment: The command actionQueue.next() is reached, gets triggered everytime, it's not a problem of not reaching the command. If I add a console.log inside actionQueue.next() definition, I can see the queue getting updated. But, even when I see the queue getting updated, sometimes $actionNext doesn't trigger an update (and with queue.shift(), one would expect the first element of the array to change).

Comment: I've noticed that the trigger is not happening when something like, 20 actions get added to the queue, and each of them takes about 100ms to finish, sometimes it gets stuck on an action and doesn't finish triggering them all.